# Using numChildren values of multiple movieclips and adding them together to obtain a sum variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

I have 15 empty(with blank keyframe) movieclips in the scene and i call png files into them.(by load(new URLRequest)) I want them to work like slots. With correspondent add PNG buttons on the scene, each slot will have a PNG. There are "substract PNG button"s on the scene

When all the slots are full, I want to show user a message (like warning_mc.visible=true)that "All 15 slots are full, please make at least one of the slots empty".

For this what i thought is to detect all the movieclips numChildren values and sum them up and with a variable that will take the sum value, if the variable value exceeds the sum, the warning message will be shown to user.

But i think numChildren values cannot be used in that way? Any other solution for this?

Comment: What have you tried?  `numChildren` will be zero if your movie is empty, so it should work the way you want.

Comment: i create integer variable for each movieclip like (var slot1:int = movieclip.numChildren; ), slot2, slot3, etc.. and then when all slots(empty in initial state) contains a png (then their numChildren will be 1) i want to take a sum like  var slotTotal:int = slot1+slot2+... and when slotTotal > 15 i want to show a message but i can't use the values slotTotal always shows zero.

Comment: Your concept isn't bad, but it's hard to help without seeing some code.  Without it, we can't say why it's not working for you.

Comment: Ok I think I found out why. Because numChildren property is READ-ONLY. That means I can't pass "1" value to a variable. People, it is so simple. A movieclip with empty keyframe and with load(new URLRequest()) i call a PNG inside this movie-clip. I can trace this movieclip numChildren changes when PNG is loaded inside. Just then can you please offer me another method for my purpose that is written clearly on my first post?

Comment: when you do `slot1:int = movieclip.numChildren;`, your storing the amount of children at that moment in time.  If something is added to movieclip, it will not be reflected in your var `slot1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a model similar to this:

```
var mySlots:Vector = new Vector<MovieClip>(mc1,mc2,mc3, mc4, mc15); //make an array/vector of all your containers

function get slotTotal():int {
    var count:int = 0;
    for(var i:int=0;i<mySlots.length;i++){ //go through each slot and see if it has children
        if(mySlots[i].numChildren > 0){
            count++;
        }    
    }
    return count;
}

function get isValid():Boolean {
   return (mySlots.length - slotTotal == 1); //if total slots is one less than all the containers, then return true
}
```

Comment: I could not implement this piece of code into mine because i load pngs into movieclips by means of a function that's triggered by button clicks. I came across with an error that avoids me putting this piece inside of a function. I created another solution for that but i am sure you have given me the solution. If i had time i would modify this for my use. So i will mark your approach as the answer.

Comment: My approach is; 15 movieclips are nested inside a container movieclip. Inside the container movieclip , i create 15 int type variables(initally set to 0). Now when png loader function is triggered, i change the value of the corresponding variable(i got the target name by click and match it to the corresponding var) to 1. I have also a variable in stage which takes sum of 15 variable. Now when the button clicked the same png loader function also checks the sum is over 15 or not and that is all.